# Encountered this error message when running a C# application accessing the webcam

Tags: c#, interop, webcam

I have an application that's running fine on a few machines but not on one critical demo unit.  It's simple winform application that accesses webcam and attempts to record a video.  This application immediately  crashes when started.  Here's the Exception message:

> *** *Exception Text* ********* System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not
>   registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) 
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindMoniker(IMoniker pmk,
>   UInt32 grfOpt, Guid& iidResult, Object& ppvResult)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(String
>   monikerName)    at DirectX.Capture.Capture.createGraph() in
>   C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\Compressed\DirectXCapture_demo_Enhanced\DirectXCapture_demo\DirectX.Capture\Capture.cs:line
>   1107    at DirectX.Capture.Capture..ctor(Filter videoDevice, Filter
>   audioDevice) in
>   C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\Compressed\DirectXCapture_demo_Enhanced\DirectXCapture_demo\DirectX.Capture\Capture.cs:line
>   928    at Ivypromise.webcame.WebCame.buttonRecord_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Project_extra\LiLi_project\Ivypromise_desktopApp\Ivypromise\Ivypromise\webcame\WebCame.cs:line
>   209    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ******* *Loaded Assemblies* ********* mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4963 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Ivypromise
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Jenny/Dropbox/To%20share/li/Release/Ivypromise.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4961 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4962 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- DirectX.Capture
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.4380.42651
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.4380.42651
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Jenny/Dropbox/To%20share/li/Release/DirectX.Capture.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- DShowNET
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.1
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Jenny/Dropbox/To%20share/li/Release/DShowNET.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.2902.0
>       Win32 Version: 5.04.00.2904
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Jenny/Dropbox/To%20share/li/Release/Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.DLL
>
> ******* *JIT Debugging* ********* To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Comment: So have you asked yourself "what is different about this machine"?

Comment: `Class not registered` your machine is missing a COM component. Just install it

Comment: Specifically, what is different about directX and the drivers for the webcam?

Comment: The machine is owned by a senior exec at a remote location so we don't have access to it all the time.  What should I look if I remote in next time?

Comment: L.B, can you please give a pointer where and what COM component should we install on that machine?

Comment: Tetsujin - we have included DirectSHow and DirectX dlls in the application package, still didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I don't know since I just interpreted your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

We switched to directShow.net dll and it worked on all our machines.  We think we were missing some webcam driver interface in our original solution.